# JS objects equality

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to play with objects alongside with `Symbol.toPrimitive` symbol in order to convert objects to primitives.

I used this code:

```
function UserEq(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function (hint) {
        alert("hint is: " + hint);
        return 0;
    };
}
function objectEqualityCheck() {
    let user1 = new UserEq("John");
    let user2 = new UserEq("Rambo");

    if (user1 == user2) alert("Equal!");
}
```

And I expect two conversions resulting in alert `Equal!`, but that is not what's hapenning...

When used like `user1 == 0` all works fine (conversion is to `number` though).

Why when two objects are compared, it does not work?

EDIT: it doesn't work with `===` as well.

Comment: Because they are two different objects in two different spaces in memory.  They are not the same object in the same allocated memory space, so by default object comparison, they are not equal

Comment: @Taplar Oh, I thought that `==` operator would make implicit conversion.

Comment: conversion occurs when you try to match two different type not when they are of same type

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to implement the concept in javascript, but other languages like java based languages also have this same issue.  They overcome it by implementing a method that defines how they are serialized or converted to a string, before simple equality will "just work".  Otherwise, a custom `equals(secondObject)` can be written and that method can check that all the internals are equal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: in js two objects are never the same, checking for equality using `==` `===` would only compare the references which are sure to be different, so its always `false` unless you are comparing the same object. `==` , `===` equality does not check for the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule in the docs for `==` defines this

> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> ```
> If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>     Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
> ```

[`TC39`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)

---

```
user1 == user2
```

Here you're comparing same type so there's no type conversion happens at all

---

ToPrimitive is called only under these conditions

- If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object,
  return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
- If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.